# Help needed with the solution about Differential Equations.

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

$$(x^2 + 4y^2)\dfrac {dx}{dy} = xy$$

In my opinion, I should separate dx and dy into opposite sites then look for mx = my or not.

Is this true? Or is it that the constant C only influences F(x) and so that makes it an important only to that part of the solution?

Thanks for help, I appreciated.

Comment: first get $dy/dx, \,$ use substitution $u = y/x$

Comment: Your differential equations textbook should have a discussion of "homogeneous" first-order DEs.  Presumably that is how @MathLover came up with the proper substitution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(x^2 + 4y^2)\dfrac {dx}{dy} = xy$$
$$(x^2 + 4y^2) = xyy'$$
$$(x^2 + 4y^2)=\dfrac x2 (y^2)'$$
$$x^2 + 4v=\dfrac x2 v'$$
$$uv' -4v=u$$
$$\left ( \dfrac v {u^4}\right)'=\dfrac 1 {u^4}$$
Where $v=y^2,u=x^2$. Integrate both sides.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Hints: $$(x^2+4y^2)\frac{dx}{dy}=xy$$

This is a homogeneous differential equation.
Put $y=vx$.then,
$$(x^2+4v^2x^2)=x^2v(v+x\frac{dv}{dx})$$
Now you can proceed. Good luck!

Comment: thank you so much.

Comment: You're welcome:)